# D3 Bar Graph: flipping the Y-axis flips my data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, axes

I ran into a common problem while making a bar graph in d3: my y-axis was upside down. After some googling, I found out that the best way to fix this is by reversing the y-domain. The only problem is, when I did that, the bars on my graph switched positions, so the largest was at the beginning instead of the end. I need the y-axis to be correct, without changing my bars.

Bars in correct positions, but the y-axis is upside-down

[image]

Bars are incorrect, but the y-axis is right-side-up

[image]

Here is the code: https://codepen.io/lucassorenson/pen/rPRadR?editors=0010

```
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(json, (d) => d[1])])
  .range([h - padding, padding]);
const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
```

This is the code that I changed. If you reverse the range ([padding, h - padding]), the bars are correct but the axis is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is simply to exchange the callback functions of the attributes "height" and "y".

Your code was:

```
...
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(json)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', 3)
    .attr('height', (d) => yScale(d[1]))
    .attr('x', function(d, i){
      return i*4 + padding
    })
    .attr('y', function(d){
      return  h - yScale(d[1]) - padding
    })
```

change it to:

```
...
svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(json)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', 3)
    .attr('y', (d) => yScale(d[1]))
    .attr('x', function(d, i){
      return i*4 + padding
    })
    .attr('height', function(d){
      return  h - yScale(d[1]) - padding
    })
```

With the attribute "y" you typically set the upper edge of the rectangle and with "height" you denote how far it goes down.